# Linq Count after removing Prefix words

Tags: c#, linq

I have word(s) with one or more prefixes (starting letters) and a list of predefined prefixes.
I want to count the number of prefixes attached to the given word.
My Code:

```
public static void main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> prefixes=new List<string>();
    prefixes.Add("im");
    prefixes.Add("anti");
    prefixes.Add("auto");
    prefixes.Add("dis");
    Console.Write(PrefixesCount("autoDiscount",prefixes));
}

public static int PrefixesCount(string word,List<string> prefixes)
{
    return (from t in prefixes where word.StartWith(t) select t).ToList<string>().Count;
}
```

> output: 1

It should return "2" as "auto" and "dis" are prefixes.

Comment: Firstly "autoDiscount" doesn't start with "dis" it contains "dis", Secondly, You need to deal with the Upper and lower cases characters.

Comment: yes Auto discount doesn't start with "dis" but it start with "auto"
if i remove "auto" then again it start with a prefix word "dis",
case sensitivity is not a big issue, I can use ToUpper() function on both to make it case in-insensitive @Ayoub_B

Comment: Do you must use LINQ?

Comment: What count should be returned in case when word is `antiPattern` and prefixes are `[ "anti", "an" ]`?

Comment: @EdwardIslam can you explain the logic for counting in "sco" as well? i don't see why

Comment: @EdwardIslam, another case - what result you expect for word `"antiPattern"` and prefixes `[ "anti", "an", "at" ]`

Answer (score 3):

You should use IndexOf instead of starts with as there are 2 words you are trying to find inside the string, and your string can only start with one word.

Also, use `ignoreCase` while doing a comparison to discard issues related to Lowercase and Uppercase comparisons.

```
public static int PrefixesCount(string word, List<string> prefixes)
{
    return (from t in prefixes where word.IndexOf(t, 
   StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >-1 select t).Count();
}
```

Comment: `.ToList<string>()` is redundant here. You can drop it and use `Count()` instead.

Comment: This will not work for OP's requirements, because he need prefixes, this approach will count all occurrences of "prefixes" even it in the end of the word

Comment: @Fabio as mentioned in his comments, he wants to count sco also, which is in middle of the word somewhere.

Comment: @TsahiAsher I used his query from the question used `IndexOf` instead of `StartsWith`, Now have removed `.ToList<string>() `since you are correct, it is not required to get the count only.

Comment: Then it definitely cannot be names as `PrefixesCount`  - it become simply string contains method - which have tons of answers on SO

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a simple while loop instead as it's more intuitive, reads and explains itself better.

The loop will continue as long as it finds a prefix and if it does, it removes it from the word.

```
public static int PrefixesCount(string word, List<string> prefixes)
{
    string prefix;
    int count = 0;
    while ((prefix = prefixes.FirstOrDefault(p => word.StartsWith(p,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))) != null)
    {
        word = word.Substring(prefix.Length);
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

Comment: OP wasn't specific in requirements, for example this will not work in case when prefixes contains other prefixes, but still need to be count. For example prefixes are [ "anti", "an" ], after "anti" prefix found it will remove it by substring and "an" will not be count

Comment: @fabio, is that *really* the requirement? doesn't make sense to me. but we can find many edge cases. for example the prefixes could be ["anti", "an", "ti"] - then what? who knows...  My answers and the others as well follows the logic that the OP introduced in his first comment

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to go recursive. For example:

```
using System.Linq;
private int CntPref(List<string> prefs, string aword) {
    int cnt = 0;
    prefs.Select((s)=>{
        if(aword.StartsWith(s)) {
            cnt++;
            cnt+=CntPrefs(prefs, aword.Substring(s.Length));
        }
    });
    return cnt,
}
```

Comment: OP wasn't specific in requirements, for example this will not work in case when prefixes contains other prefixes, but still need to be count. For example prefixes are [ "anti", "an" ], after "anti" prefix found it will remove it by `substring` and "an" will not be count.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, I solved *Lambda* and *Linq* without using **StringComparison**. 
You could write an extension method for containing control in the extension method, then you obtain ignore case sensitivity with **StringComparison**. Like [Case insensitive 'Contains(string)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/444798/case-insensitive-containsstring) check the @JaredPar's answer.

```
 public static int PrefixesCount(string word, List<string> prefixes)
 {        
     var prefixCountWithLinq = from p in prefixes
                              where word.ToLower().Contains(p)
                              select(p).ToList();

     var prefixCountWithlamda = prefixes.Count(x => word.ToLower().Contains(x));

     return prefixCountWithLinq.Count();
  }
```

Return: 2

Hope it helps to you.